# Google chrome only partially loading background images

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser

I am having trouble with my website in chrome on both windows and mac, I have had multiple people test it on multiple computers and this behaviour is not 100% of the time but is very common. The website in it's current state can be viewed at: [georgereith.com/test/](http://georgereith.com/test/)

The image below shows how my website should look currently:

[image: website screenshot]

However when some people with chrome open it, it loads like this:

[image: broken website screenshot]

The strange behaviour is that when you start to highlight things where the missing background should be, chrome appears to render more of the background:

[image: highlighted broken website screenshot]

Does anyone know what could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: I don't get this behavior in Chrome 17 on Win7.

Comment: @EmilStenström Thanks, have you tried hard refreshing? I can report it happening from 16.0.912.63 on Win7

Comment: Ahh, it seems to be only on *some* page loads, reloading a couple of times makes it show up here too.

Comment: Confirmed. Have you tried on other Webkit-based browsers to see if this is a Chrome or Webkit issue?

Comment: @Cicada I was unable to reproduce the issue in safari, so I am thinking it is a chrome issue

Comment: Then your best luck is to file a bug in the Chrome tracker, I believe.

Comment: I'm getting this problem with my own site, and I'm getting the same error on your site.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a Chrome bug, but I can't find any reference to it.

It seems to go away when I start the web inspector, so maybe you could try to run some dummy javascript on the element that's misbehaving (Note: I'm just guessing here):

```
var acc = document.getElementById("accordion");
acc.className = acc.className;
```

This should force a reflow.

Comment: The thing with the web inspector I noticed also, I believe it is the same as the highlighting it forces Chrome to redraw that area of the bitmap. I thing the inspector forces it to redraw the entire viewport.