# JQuery Animations only work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Please forgive me if I did this wrong. I am a newb to coding and this is my first StackOverflow post as well:

Can anyone help me with why my patchwork JQuery is not functioning properly in Chrome or IE? It works fine in Firefox. In Chrome the whole page changes while the code block is executing then it returns to normal. It IE the transitions don't work. I do have some tabs in my code. Could that be the problem? Please help.

Here is the website: http://rbrewer.mydevryportfolio.com/

Here is my Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("document").ready(function() {
        flag=true;
        $(window).scroll(function(){
        st = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(st>500){
            if(flag);
            $("#cwpBox").css("opacity", ".2");
            $("#psLogo").css("top","0px");
            $("#psLogo").css("opacity","1");
            $("#psBar").css("width","98%");
            $("#psLabel").css("opacity","1");
            $("#psSkill").css("opacity","1");
            setTimeout (function(){
                $("#aiLogo").css("top","0px");
                $("#aiLogo").css("opacity","1");
                $("#aiBar").css("width","93%");
                $("#aiLabel").css("opacity","1");
                $("#aiSkill").css("opacity","1");
                }, 500);
            setTimeout (function(){
                $("#htmlLogo").css("top","0px");
                $("#htmlLogo").css("opacity","1");
                $("#htmlBar").css("width","80%");
                $("#htmlLabel").css("opacity","1");
                $("#htmlSkill").css("opacity","1");
                }, 1000);
            setTimeout (function(){
                $("#cssLogo").css("top","0px");
                $("#cssLogo").css("opacity","1");
                $("#cssBar").css("width","80%");
                $("#cssLabel").css("opacity","1");
                $("#cssSkill").css("opacity","1");
                }, 1500);
            setTimeout (function(){
                $("#javaLogo").css("top","0px");
                $("#javaLogo").css("opacity","1");
                $("#javaBar").css("width","60%");
                $("#javaLabel").css("opacity","1");
                $("#javaSkill").css("opacity","1");
                }, 2000);
            setTimeout (function(){
                $("#phpLogo").css("top","0px");
                $("#phpLogo").css("opacity","1");
                $("#phpBar").css("width","40%");
                $("#phpLabel").css("opacity","1");
                $("#phpSkill").css("opacity","1");
                }, 2500);
            /*setTimeout (function(){$("#psLabel").css("opacity","1")}
            , 1600);
            setTimeout (function(){$("#psSkill").css("opacity","1")}
            , 2100)*/
        }
        else if (st<500){
            if(flag);
            $("#cwpBox").css("opacity", "1");
            $("#psLogo").css("top","100px");
            $("#psLogo").css("opacity","0");
            $("#psBar").css("width","0");
            $("#psLabel").css("opacity","0");
            $("#psSkill").css("opacity","0");
            setTimeout (function(){
                $("#aiLogo").css("top","100px");
                $("#aiLogo").css("opacity","0");
                $("#aiBar").css("width","0");
                $("#aiLabel").css("opacity","0");
                $("#aiSkill").css("opacity","0");
                }, 500);
            setTimeout (function(){
                $("#htmlLogo").css("top","100px");
                $("#htmlLogo").css("opacity","0");
                $("#htmlBar").css("width","0");
                $("#htmlLabel").css("opacity","0");
                $("#htmlSkill").css("opacity","0");
                }, 1000);
            setTimeout (function(){
                $("#cssLogo").css("top","100px");
                $("#cssLogo").css("opacity","0");
                $("#cssBar").css("width","0");
                $("#cssLabel").css("opacity","0");
                $("#cssSkill").css("opacity","0");
                }, 1500);
            setTimeout (function(){
                $("#javaLogo").css("top","100px");
                $("#javaLogo").css("opacity","0");
                $("#javaBar").css("width","0");
                $("#javaLabel").css("opacity","0");
                $("#javaSkill").css("opacity","0");
                }, 2000);
            setTimeout (function(){
                $("#phpLogo").css("top","100px");
                $("#phpLogo").css("opacity","0");
                $("#phpBar").css("width","0");
                $("#phpLabel").css("opacity","0");
                $("#phpSkill").css("opacity","0");
                }, 2500);


        }//--closes else if
        else{flag=false;}
        }); //--closes window.scroll function
    }); //--closes document ready function
    </script>
```

Comment: Works fine on Safari 7.0.3.

Comment: Thanks Tiago!  I hadn't checked it on Safari yet but that is good to know. I'm still befuddled as to why Chrome changes my background while the code is executing.  The page goes back to normal after all the setTimeouts or CSS transitions delays are done. Confused!

Answer (score 0):

That's really strange behaviour. It might not be the best solution, but I found I got it to work in Chrome by assigning the background image to the html in the CSS rather than the body. You'll have to remove the body background color as well. I'll be interested to see what the actual core problem is.

Comment: Thank you Andrew!  It's good to know there is a fix for Chrome and reassuring to know that it is strange to someone else too.

Comment: Just an FYI update, putting CSS background properties under the HTML tag did work but if you refresh the page after the transitions have completed it still breaks the render and the background changes again.

Comment: It's weird. I disabled javascript and still reproduced the error. So it's something else. I know Chrome used to have a bug with caching background images. They describe the same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692921/google-chrome-only-partially-loading-background-images as soon as you inspect an element it loads in.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I improved the render problem by eliminating two unnecessary CSS properties from `body` (`position:relative` & `z-index:-99`) but now I'm having an issue with the hover on the top navigation links not performing when you scroll down on the page. Scrolling down essentially hides all the elements under the top nav bar so Chrome is having an issue with repainting and/or positioning or something. The CSS positioning for the whole header is a bit of a patchwork job so it's got to be in there somewhere but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Oh yeah and if I disable Javascript then the top-nav hover issue goes away. Part of my code does add a positioning property to the FlipBoxes on scroll so it must be how Chrome is handling the stack order and rendering all the layers.  Hopefully I'll figure this out.

Comment: just an FYI in case you were curious. The problem boiled down to inconsistent use of the z-index property. Once I changed all my z-index values to either 0, 1 or 2 Chrome had no issues.  I think Chrome got angry with me using z-index properties of -99 and 200, etc. So problem solved! Cheers!